# TypeError: Singleton array array('[0.1, 0, 0.26, 0.0, 0.83], etc...) dtype='<U797') cannot be considered a valid collection

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to train a ML model to take in MIDI sequences and output MIDI sequences. I only have 20 datapoints of varying lengths and they're written into .txt files. My X_data looks like: [0.1, 0, 0.2631578947368421, 0.0, 0.83],[0.4, 0, 0.4473678486840675, 0.8, 1.0], etc.. while my Y_data looks like: [(0.1, 0.24), (0.3, 0), (0.1, 0.24), etc...],[(0.4, 0.35), (0.4, 0), etc...] . Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

with open(r'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\MidiProcessedData\X_data.txt', 'r') as file:
    X = file.read()
with open(r'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\MidiProcessedData\Y_data.txt', 'r') as file:
    y = file.read()

# Convert data to Numpy Array
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

# Split the dataset into training and validation sets
X_train, X_train, y_train,  = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, train_size=0.7, random_state=42)
X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_temp, y_temp, test_size=0.5, train_size=0.5, random_state=42)

# Define the LSTM model
model = Sequential([
    LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 1)),  # Smaller LSTM layer
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),  # Smaller Dense layer
    Dense(1, activation='linear')  # Output layer with linear activation
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=8, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
```

I tried changing the test and train size to each extreme (0.1-0.9), I tried using 'np.loadtxt' to import the data. I tried removing the validation set entirely. I tried importing the data as a .json.
I tried re-formatting the X_data to be:
[data, data, data]
[data, data, data]
etc...
None of what I tried actually solved the issue which makes me believe the issue lies in the formatting of my data.

Comment: You should y store your data that way, and  `X = np.array(X)` is definitely not the correct way to turn it into a numpy array. Almost certainly, you should just not be using plain text to begin with, and use some other format.